# How do I make a for loop that creates a new data table each iteration

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping, rvest

I have a for loop web scraping a website every year, but I want it to create a new data frame for each year, here is my code:

```
for (pageresult in seq(from =2021, to =1997, by = -1)){

url5 = paste0("https://www.boxofficemojo.com/year/world/", pageresult, "/")

pageresult = data.frame()

#loop for every year

(html <- rvest::read_html(url5))

pageresult <-as.data.frame(html %>% rvest::html_elements(css = "table") %>%

.[[1]] %>%

rvest::html_table())

colnames(pageresult)[7] <- "percent2"

colnames(pageresult)[2] <- "name"

colnames(pageresult)[1] <- "rank_WBO"

}
```

This unfortunately creates a case were I get a single data frame called "pageresult", it does successfully loop though, I just don't know how to save each data frame. I would like to have several data frames called 2021,2020,2019 etc. Thank you very much for your help

Doing this will give me a data frame called pageresult and shows me the information I need but for 1997, I need all the years. I would have liked to have multiple data frames from 2021 to 1997.

Answer (score 0):

First, use diffeeent names for your index number (pageresult) and the data you create within each loop, e.g. use 'page_data' instead of 'pageresult'.

Before doing your loop, create an empty list like:

```
results_list <- list()
```

Then, at the end of each loop, add:

```
results_list[[2022 - pageresult]] <- page_data
```

All together:

```
results_list <- list()

for (pageresult in seq(from =2021, to =1997, by = -1)){

url5 = paste0("https://www.boxofficemojo.com/year/world/", pageresult, "/")

#loop for every year

(html <- rvest::read_html(url5))

page_data <-as.data.frame(html %>% rvest::html_elements(css = "table") %>%

.[[1]] %>%

rvest::html_table())

colnames(page_data)[7] <- "percent2"

colnames(page_data)[2] <- "name"

colnames(page_data)[1] <- "rank_WBO"

results_list[[2022 - pageresult]] <- page_data

}
```